# Can unix_timestamp() return unix time in milliseconds in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to get the unix time from a timestamp field in milliseconds (13 digits) but currently it returns in seconds (10 digits).

```
scala> var df = Seq("2017-01-18 11:00:00.000", "2017-01-18 11:00:00.123", "2017-01-18 11:00:00.882", "2017-01-18 11:00:02.432").toDF()
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> df = df.selectExpr("value timeString", "cast(value as timestamp) time")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [timeString: string, time: timestamp]


scala> df = df.withColumn("unix_time", unix_timestamp(df("time")))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [timeString: string, time: timestamp ... 1 more field]

scala> df.take(4)
res63: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array(
[2017-01-18 11:00:00.000,2017-01-18 11:00:00.0,1484758800], 
[2017-01-18 11:00:00.123,2017-01-18 11:00:00.123,1484758800], 
[2017-01-18 11:00:00.882,2017-01-18 11:00:00.882,1484758800], 
[2017-01-18 11:00:02.432,2017-01-18 11:00:02.432,1484758802])
```

Even though `2017-01-18 11:00:00.123` and `2017-01-18 11:00:00.000` are different, I get the same unix time back `1484758800`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10):

Milliseconds hide in fraction part timestamp format

Try this:

```
df = df.withColumn("time_in_milliseconds", col("time").cast("double"))
```

You'll get something like 1484758800.792, where 792 it's milliseconds

At least it's works for me (Scala, Spark, Hive)

Comment: This is also of particular usefulness if you need to round a time field to the nearest second. unix_timestamp() does not properly round the timestamp, instead it takes the mathematical floor of the time down to the seconds, ignoring the milliseconds fraction. The solution in this answer provides a decimal unix time which can be rounded, thus providing a way to round a timestamp to the nearest second.

Answer (score 6):

Implementing the approach suggested in [Dao Thi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42551255/4006204)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('22-Jul-2018 04:21:18.792 UTC', ),('23-Jul-2018 04:21:25.888 UTC',)], ['TIME'])
df.show(2,False)
df.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+
|TIME                        |
+----------------------------+
|22-Jul-2018 04:21:18.792 UTC|
|23-Jul-2018 04:21:25.888 UTC|
+----------------------------+
root
|-- TIME: string (nullable = true)
```

Converting **string time-format** (including milliseconds ) to **unix_timestamp(double)**. Extracting milliseconds from string using substring method (start_position = -7, length_of_substring=3) and Adding milliseconds seperately to unix_timestamp. (Cast  to substring to float for adding)

```
df1 = df.withColumn("unix_timestamp",F.unix_timestamp(df.TIME,'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z') + F.substring(df.TIME,-7,3).cast('float')/1000)
```

Converting **unix_timestamp(double)** to **timestamp datatype** in Spark.

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("TimestampType",F.to_timestamp(df1["unix_timestamp"]))
df2.show(n=2,truncate=False)
```

This will give you following output

```
+----------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|TIME                        |unix_timestamp  |TimestampType          |
+----------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|22-Jul-2018 04:21:18.792 UTC|1.532233278792E9|2018-07-22 04:21:18.792|
|23-Jul-2018 04:21:25.888 UTC|1.532319685888E9|2018-07-23 04:21:25.888|
+----------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

Checking the Schema:

```
df2.printSchema()


root
 |-- TIME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- unix_timestamp: double (nullable = true)
 |-- TimestampType: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 5):

It cannot be done with unix_timestamp() but since Spark 3.1.0 there is a built-in function called unix_millis():

> unix_millis(timestamp) - Returns the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. Truncates higher levels of precision.

Answer (score 4):

`unix_timestamp()` returns unix timestamp in seconds.

The last 3 digits in the timestamps are the same as the last 3 digits of the milliseconds string (`1.999sec = 1999 milliseconds`), so just take the last 3 digits of the timestamps string and append them to the end of the milliseconds string.

Answer (score 3):

**Up to Spark version 3.0.1 it is not possible to convert a timestamp into unix time in milliseconds using the SQL built-in function `unix_timestamp`.**

According to the code on Spark's [DateTimeUtils](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/DateTimeUtils.scala#L39)

> "Timestamps are exposed externally as `java.sql.Timestamp` and are stored internally as `longs`, which are capable of storing timestamps with microsecond precision."

Therefore, if you define a UDF that has a `java.sql.Timestamp` as input you can  call `getTime` for a Long in millisecond. If you apply `unix_timestamp` you will only get unix time with precision in seconds.

```scala
val tsConversionToLongUdf = udf((ts: java.sql.Timestamp) => ts.getTime)
```

Applying this to a variety of Timestamps:

```scala
val df = Seq("2017-01-18 11:00:00.000", "2017-01-18 11:00:00.111", "2017-01-18 11:00:00.110", "2017-01-18 11:00:00.100")
  .toDF("timestampString")
  .withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp(col("timestampString")))
  .withColumn("timestampConversionToLong", tsConversionToLongUdf(col("timestamp")))
  .withColumn("timestampUnixTimestamp", unix_timestamp(col("timestamp")))

df.printSchema()
df.show(false)

// returns
root
 |-- timestampString: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampConversionToLong: long (nullable = false)
 |-- timestampCastAsLong: long (nullable = true)

+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+
|timestampString        |timestamp              |timestampConversionToLong|timestampUnixTimestamp|
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+
|2017-01-18 11:00:00.000|2017-01-18 11:00:00    |1484733600000            |1484733600         |
|2017-01-18 11:00:00.111|2017-01-18 11:00:00.111|1484733600111            |1484733600         |
|2017-01-18 11:00:00.110|2017-01-18 11:00:00.11 |1484733600110            |1484733600         |
|2017-01-18 11:00:00.100|2017-01-18 11:00:00.1  |1484733600100            |1484733600         |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, same with @Тимур Залимов just cast it

```bash
>>> df2 = df_msg.withColumn("datetime", F.col("timestamp").cast("timestamp")).withColumn("timestamp_back" , F.col("datetime").cast("double"))
>>> r = df2.rdd.take(1)[0]
>>> r.timestamp_back                                                            
1666509660.071501
>>> r.timestamp
1666509660.071501
>>> r.datetime
datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 23, 15, 21, 0, 71501)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get number of milliseconds since UTC epoch, one could do:

```
scala> spark.sql("select unix_millis(current_timestamp())").show(truncate=false)
+--------------------------------+
|unix_millis(current_timestamp())|
+--------------------------------+
|1705680115519                   |
+--------------------------------+
```